# Cannot create cursor with MySQLdb

Tags: python, mysql, mysql-python

I am connecting to a database with the following code:

```
#generate connection to database
def connection():
    return MySQLdb.connect(host   = __HOST__,
                           user   = __USER__,
                           passwd = __PASS__,
                           port   = __PORT__,
                           db     = __DFDB__)
db = connection()
```

After connecting I am able to see that the connection is open

```
<_mysql.connection open to 'db' at memory>
```

Yet I an unable to get a cursor:

```
>>> db.cursor()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/Python/2.7.3/lib/python2.7/site-packages/MySQL_python-1.2.3-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg/MySQLdb/connections.py", line 243, in cursor
    return (cursorclass or self.cursorclass)(self)
AttributeError: 'Connection' object has no attribute 'cursorclass'
```

I am really not sure what is going on here, I am effectively copying the MySQLdb documentation verbatim. I've seen fixes for using a dictionary class but I am just interested in using the standard cursor. What is the problem here? I am using python 2.7.3 and MySQLdb 1.2.3.

Here is more error output:

```
*** glibc detected *** python: free(): invalid pointer: 0x0000000009489520 ***
======= Backtrace: =========
/lib64/libc.so.6(+0x760e6)[0x7fc806f6d0e6]
/usr/local/mysql-5.1.49/lib64/libmysqlclient_r.so.16(+0x7d150)[0x7fc8004b4150]
/usr/local/mysql-5.1.49/lib64/libmysqlclient_r.so.16(mysql_close+0x72)[0x7fc8004b4bb2]
/usr/local/Python/2.7.3/lib/python2.7/site-packages/MySQL_python-1.2.3-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg/_mysql.so(+0x7510)[0x7fc800850510]
/usr/local/Python/2.7.3/lib/python2.7/site-packages/MySQL_python-1.2.3-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg/_mysql.so(+0x75df)[0x7fc8008505df]
python[0x464673]
python[0x4f37b3]
python[0x4fc1ba]
python[0x4c794b]
python[0x4c795b]
python[0x4487e3]
python(PyDict_SetItem+0x70)[0x4496e0]
python(PyDict_SetItemString+0x4b)[0x44a3cb]
python(PyImport_Cleanup+0xcc)[0x4b12bc]
python(Py_Finalize+0xfb)[0x4bfe5b]
python(Py_Main+0x4f6)[0x414706]
/lib64/libc.so.6(__libc_start_main+0xfd)[0x7fc806f15cdd]
python[0x413e39]
======= Memory map: ========
00400000-0055e000 r-xp 00000000 00:15 145437598                          /usr/local/Python/2.7.3/bin/python2.7
0075d000-00799000 rw-p 0015d000 00:15 145437598                          /usr/local/Python/2.7.3/bin/python2.7
00799000-007a8000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
01d98000-094db000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0                                  [heap]
7fc7f8000000-7fc7f8021000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
7fc7f8021000-7fc7fc000000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0
7fc7fc314000-7fc7fc32a000 r-xp 00000000 fd:01 406589                     /lib64/libresolv-2.12.so
7fc7fc32a000-7fc7fc52a000 ---p 00016000 fd:01 406589                     /lib64/libresolv-2.12.so
7fc7fc52a000-7fc7fc52b000 r--p 00016000 fd:01 406589                     /lib64/libresolv-2.12.so
7fc7fc52b000-7fc7fc52c000 rw-p 00017000 fd:01 406589                     /lib64/libresolv-2.12.so
7fc7fc52c000-7fc7fc52e000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
7fc7fc52e000-7fc7fc533000 r-xp 00000000 fd:01 393350                     /lib64/libnss_dns-2.12.so
7fc7fc533000-7fc7fc732000 ---p 00005000 fd:01 393350                     /lib64/libnss_dns-2.12.so
7fc7fc732000-7fc7fc733000 r--p 00004000 fd:01 393350                     /lib64/libnss_dns-2.12.so
7fc7fc733000-7fc7fc734000 rw-p 00005000 fd:01 393350                     /lib64/libnss_dns-2.12.so
7fc7fc734000-7fc7fc740000 r-xp 00000000 fd:01 402938                     /lib64/libnss_files-2.12.so
7fc7fc740000-7fc7fc940000 ---p 0000c000 fd:01 402938                     /lib64/libnss_files-2.12.so
7fc7fc940000-7fc7fc941000 r--p 0000c000 fd:01 402938                     /lib64/libnss_files-2.12.so
7fc7fc941000-7fc7fc942000 rw-p 0000d000 fd:01 402938                     /lib64/libnss_files-2.12.so
7fc7fc942000-7fc7fc958000 r-xp 00000000 fd:01 393226                     /lib64/libgcc_s-4.4.7-20120601.so.1
7fc7fc958000-7fc7fcb57000 ---p 00016000 fd:01 393226                     /lib64/libgcc_s-4.4.7-20120601.so.1
7fc7fcb57000-7fc7fcb58000 rw-p 00015000 fd:01 393226                     /lib64/
libgcc_s-4.4.7-20120601.so.1
7fc7fcb58000-7fc7fcb59000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0
7fc7fcb59000-7fc7fd559000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
7fc7fd559000-7fc7fd55d000 r-xp 00000000 00:15 144816624                  /usr/local/Python/2.7.3/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/_locale.so
7fc7fd55d000-7fc7fd75d000 ---p 00004000 00:15 144816624                  /usr/local/Python/2.7.3/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/_locale.so
7fc7fd75d000-7fc7fd75e000 rw-p 00004000 00:15 144816624                  /usr/local/Python/2.7.3/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/_locale.so
7fc7fd75e000-7fc7fd761000 r-xp 00000000 00:15 160415290                  /usr/local/Python/2.7.3/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/_heapq.so
7fc7fd761000-7fc7fd961000 ---p 00003000 00:15 160415290                  /usr/local/Python/2.7.3/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/_heapq.so
7fc7fd961000-7fc7fd963000 rw-p 00003000 00:15 160415290                  /usr/local/Python/2.7.3/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/_heapq.so
7fc7fd963000-7fc7fd965000 r-xp 00000000 00:15 160415289                  /usr/local/Python/2.7.3/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/_bisect.so
7fc7fd965000-7fc7fdb64000 ---p 00002000 00:15 160415289                  /usr/local/Python/2.7.3/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/_bisect.so
7fc7fdb64000-7fc7fdb65000 rw-p 00001000 00:15 160415289                  /usr/local/Python/2.7.3/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/_bisect.so
7fc7fdb65000-7fc7fdb6f000 r-xp 00000000 00:15 160415285                  /usr/local/Python/2.7.3/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/itertools.so
7fc7fdb6f000-7fc7fdd6e000 ---p 0000a000 00:15 160415285                  /usr/local/Python/2.7.3/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/itertools.so
7fc7fdd6e000-7fc7fdd73000 rw-p 00009000 00:15 160415285                  /usr/local/Python/2.7.3/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/itertools.so
7fc7fdd73000-7fc7fdd7b000 r-xp 00000000 00:15 160415291                  /usr/local/Python/2.7.3/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/operator.so
7fc7fdd7b000-7fc7fdf7a000 ---p 00008000 00:15 160415291                  /usr/local/Python/2.7.3/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/operator.so
7fc7fdf7a000-7fc7fdf7c000 rw-p 00007000 00:15 160415291                  /usr/local/Python/2.7.3/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/operator.so
7fc7fdf7c000-7fc7fdf83000 r-xp 00000000 00:15 160415288                  /usr/local/Python/2.7.3/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/_collections.so
7fc7fdf83000-7fc7fe182000 ---p 00007000 00:15 160415288                  /usr/local/Python/2.7.3/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/_collections.so
7fc7fe182000-7fc7fe184000 rw-p 00006000 00:15 160415288                  /usr/local/Python/2.7.3/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/_collections.so
7fc7fe2f1000-7fc7fe2f9000 r-xp 00000000 00:15 160415279                  /usr/local/Python/2.7.3/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/array.so
7fc7fe2f9000-7fc7fe4f8000 ---p 00008000 00:15 160415279                  /usr/local/Python/2.7.3/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/array.so
7fc7fe4f8000-7fc7fe4fb000 rw-p 00007000 00:15 160415279                  /usr/local/Python/2.7.3/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/array.so
7fc7ff54c000-7fc7ff55e000 r-xp 00000000 00:15 160415284                  /usr/local/Python/2.7.3/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/datetime.so
7fc7ff55e000-7fc7ff75d000 ---p 00012000 00:15 160415284                  /usr/local/Python/2.7.3/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/datetime.so
7fc7ff75d000-7fc7ff761000 rw-p 00011000 00:15 160415284                  /usr/local/Python/2.7.3/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/datetime.so
7fc7ff761000-7fc7ff765000 r-xp 00000000 00:15 160415283                  /usr/local/Python/2.7.3/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/time.so
7fc7ff765000-7fc7ff964000 ---p 00004000 00:15 160415283                  /usr/local/Python/2.7.3/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/time.so
7fc7ff964000-7fc7ff966000 rw-p 00003000 00:15 160415283                  /usr/local/Python/2.7.3/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/time.so
7fc7ff966000-7fc7ff96e000 r-xp 00000000 00:15 160415281                  /usr/local/Python/2.7.3/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/math.so
7fc7ff96e000-7fc7ffb6d000 ---p 00008000 00:15 160415281                  /usr/local/Python/2.7.3/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/math.so
7fc7ffb6d000-7fc7ffb6f000 rw-p 00007000 00:15 160415281                  /usr/lo
cal/Python/2.7.3/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/math.so
7fc7ffb6f000-7fc7ffbcc000 r-xp 00000000 fd:01 393221                     /lib64/libfreebl3.so
7fc7ffbcc000-7fc7ffdcb000 ---p 0005d000 fd:01 393221                     /lib64/libfreebl3.so
7fc7ffdcb000-7fc7ffdcc000 r--p 0005c000 fd:01 393221                     /lib64/libfreebl3.so
7fc7ffdcc000-7fc7ffdcd000 rw-p 0005d000 fd:01 393221                     /lib64/libfreebl3.so
7fc7ffdcd000-7fc7ffdd1000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
7fc7ffdd1000-7fc7ffde7000 r-xp 00000000 fd:01 394125                     /lib64/libnsl-2.12.so
7fc7ffde7000-7fc7fffe6000 ---p 00016000 fd:01 394125                     /lib64/libnsl-2.12.so
7fc7fffe6000-7fc7fffe7000 r--p 00015000 fd:01 394125                     /lib64/libnsl-2.12.so
7fc7fffe7000-7fc7fffe8000 rw-p 00016000 fd:01 394125                     /lib64/libnsl-2.12.so
7fc7fffe8000-7fc7fffea000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
7fc7fffea000-7fc7ffff1000 r-xp 00000000 fd:01 393248                     /lib64/libcrypt-2.12.so
7fc7ffff1000-7fc8001f1000 ---p 00007000 fd:01 393248                     /lib64/libcrypt-2.12.so
7fc8001f1000-7fc8001f2000 r--p 00007000 fd:01 393248                     /lib64/libcrypt-2.12.so
7fc8001f2000-7fc8001f3000 rw-p 00008000 fd:01 393248                     /lib64/libcrypt-2.12.so
7fc8001f3000-7fc800221000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
7fc800221000-7fc800236000 r-xp 00000000 fd:01 393320                     /lib64/libz.so.1.2.3
7fc800236000-7fc800435000 ---p 00015000 fd:01 393320                     /lib64/libz.so.1.2.3
7fc800435000-7fc800436000 r--p 00014000 fd:01 393320                     /lib64/libz.so.1.2.3
7fc800436000-7fc800437000 rw-p 00015000 fd:01 393320                     /lib64/libz.so.1.2.3
7fc800437000-7fc80060a000 r-xp 00000000 00:15 153064441                  /usr/local/mysql-5.1.49/lib64/libmysqlclient_r.so.16
7fc80060a000-7fc80080a000 ---p 001d3000 00:15 153064441                  /usr/local/mysql-5.1.49/lib64/libmysqlclient_r.so.16
7fc80080a000-7fc800848000 rw-p 001d3000 00:15 153064441                  /usr/local/mysql-5.1.49/lib64/libmysqlclient_r.so.16
7fc800848000-7fc800849000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
7fc800849000-7fc800853000 r-xp 00000000 00:15 135828401                  /usr/local/Python/2.7.3/lib/python2.7/site-packages/MySQL_python-1.2.3-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg/_mysql.so
7fc800853000-7fc800a52000 ---p 0000a000 00:15 135828401                  /usr/local/Python/2.7.3/lib/python2.7/site-packages/MySQL_python-1.2.3-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg/_mysql.soAborted
```

Comment: I missed it when I copied the trace initially, see the OP.

Comment: Curious indeed; that implies that the `Connection` instance was not properly initialized. Is there a `db.default_cursor` attribute? If so, setting `db.cursorclass = db.default_cursor` will fix this specific problem, but reading the [source code](https://github.com/farcepest/MySQLdb1/blob/master/MySQLdb/connections.py) the error you see *should not ever happen*.

Comment: Also interesting: you have a `_mysql.connection` object, **not** a `MySQLdb.connections.Connection` object. Not certain about that part; the latter is a subclass of the former (which is a C type) so the repr may perhaps still use `_mysql.connection` as the type name.

Comment: You could update your question with that info; just [edit] it.

Comment: I updated the post with all of the error output I can get a hold of.

Comment: So my sysadmin is confirming the same thing, it works for other versions of python (2.6, 3) but not 2.7. I'm guessing something is wrong in the configuration for 2.7.

Answer (score 0):

use this code :

```
import sys
import MySQLdb
import re
mydb = MySQLdb.connect(host='localhost',
user='root',
passwd='shailang',
db='mydb')
cursor = mydb.cursor()
```